How to fix InteliJ compilier that can't detect that project path has changed and that can't understand characters that are not English ones?


I tried moving to publics folder it still cant be fixed
I tried checking path of the compilier and it is correct, i tried disabling anti virus still no fix i dont have a damn idea what i need to do.
Is there any fix that doesnt include changing my whole users folder with recovering my files ?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

That being said: I don't see any connection between the question in the title, the screenshot and the text of your post. Please clarify.

It does look like the error is that your IDE doesn't have the correctly accented user name in the folder it's looking at, in fairness.  Not that there's anything to do about that except go through every option and path in your IDE for the wrong, unaccented name.

I fixed it by using System locale and using unicode utf8
